# Java Model View Controller for file reading

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am having a lot of trouble designing a small program that reads a text document and writes statistics to a text file. We have to use a model-view-controller format that we haven't learned yet!

Basically, the model class represents text from a text file and I need it to be stored in a String or String array. It also has to have methods to report number of words and stuff like that. The view class needs to have bufferedreader and writer. The control class creates the objects and calls the printResults() method.

So I started with my control class having something like:

```
Model model = new Model();
View view = new View( model );

view.writeFile();
```

I have a feeling this is incorrect. How do I make my model class represent a text document, and send it to the View class to read it, and then have the view class invoke methods from the model class to write statistics? Is there a better approach or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Is there any user interface in your program? Maybe I am wrong, but by essence the MVC pattern involves a GUI (conceptualized as the View).

Comment: There is no input. I just have a txt file that I need to read and write statistics for. The control is just there to initiate the program.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model makes perfect sense. You are using your View class to move data into and out of the model, and I guess that's reasonable.
Normally a view is more visual than that. I would think the View would be some window to display the text file. Maybe this could be part of a GUI to allow the user to choose the file to open and the file we are saving.

The Controller is often the place where your program responds to user input. But if you do not need to build a UI for this project, then your interpretation of "View" and "Controller" sound good. If this program was being written with, say, Swing, then your Controller would still be doing what you described. But it would do those things in response to the user clicking a save button or a file-open button.

You should probably do some reading about the Model-View-Controller design pattern if are new to it. For instance, see [Oracle's technetwork article on MVC.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html)

Comment: How do I make my view and model classes aware of each other without having to declare a view object in the model class and a model object in the view class? This would be an infinite loop

Comment: The 2 classes can have references to each other (fields) . This is not a loop at all - infinite or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
   How do I make my view and model classes aware of each other
 without having to declare a view object in the model class and
 a model object in the view class?
```

-This the job of the controller. Normally, you would create a Model and View field in the 
the Controller class  with their 'setters' and 'getters'. Then in the main program class you would create the View and Model objects and set them to the fields of your Controller class. This way each time you want to relay data between the View and Model, you just call the methods of each using the corresponding fields in your Controllers.

For example, Let's say you want to double a number entered by the user and display it. In the Controller object's implementation, you call the View's method to get the user input and pass it on as an argument to the Model's method. Then you assign the returned value, or double the number, of the Model's method and pass it back to the View or a method that displays the result in whatever fashion is desired.